# Retrieve triggered vSphere alarms

Tags: c#, vmware, vsphere

I manage several different vSphere infrastructures and I have to check them daily for alarms.

I'm writing a C# application that I can run to check them and send an email notifying me of any alarms that have triggered.

How can I get this info in c#?

Answer (score 1):

This should already be built in to the vCenter Servers SMTP agent, so you should be able to setup an Alarm Action to send an automatic email when the alarm triggers. I'm not sure what version you are using, but have a look at the documentation on the VMWare website:

http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp#working_with_alarms/c_email_notifications_as_alarm_actions.html